# I have and Azure App Service Running a Web Application and I want to authenticate using a popup window

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, popupwindow, microsoft.identity.web

I have an Azure App Service Running a Web Application (NOT a single page app and NOT using MSAL). I am using C# MVC ASP.NET CORE I am using the MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication service.

My authentication currently works perfectly however, I have a senario where I need the authentication to happen in a popup window instead of redirecting to a new page for the authentication and back again.

I know popup authentication can be accomplished with a single page app and MSAL.js but I dont want to start again. I am open to options for a hybrid approch but I would like to stay with my current authentication process if possible.

Can the `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)` be extended to include a popup window?

Here is a snippet from my startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddOptions();

            var graphBaseUrl = Configuration["Graph:BaseUrl"]; //"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
    
            var userReadScope = "user.read";
    
            string[] initialScopes = new string[] { userReadScope };
    
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
                            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                            .AddMicrosoftGraph(graphBaseUrl, userReadScope)
                            .AddSessionTokenCaches();
    
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    
            services.AddRazorPages();

}
```

Ive tried to create a hybrid with MSAL.js but I could not figure out how to merge them.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication in a popup window using `MSAL.js` in conjunction with the `MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` service in an ASP.NET Core MVC app.

- In _Layout.cshtml file, add the below script tags to include the MSAL.js library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   @await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.CdnScripts.IncludeAsync(User)
</head>
<body>
   @await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.CdnScripts.IncludeAsync(User)
</body>
</html>
```

- Add a new JavaScript file with `auth-popup.js` to your `wwwroot/js` folder.

```
var msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'Client_Id',
        authority: 'AZURE_AD_AUTHORITY',
        redirectUri: 'REDIRECT_URI',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    }
};

var msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

function openAuthPopup() {
    msalInstance.loginPopup()
        .then(response => {
          })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

- In `Startup.cs` file to inject the `ITokenAcquisition` interface into your controllers. Modify the ConfigureServices method as shown below.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(graphBaseUrl, userReadScope)
        .AddSessionTokenCaches();

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddRazorPages();
  
    services.AddScoped<ITokenAcquisition>(provider =>
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var tokenAcquisition = provider.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();
        tokenAcquisition.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        return tokenAcquisition;
    });
}
```

- In your view, add a button for triggering the `openAuthPopup()` function.

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>    
    <button onclick="openAuthPopup()">Authenticate</button>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/auth-popup.js"></script>
}
```

For more information, refer to [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-page-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-angular) and [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847081/mvc-5-c-sharp-window-authentication-pop-up-when-i-navigate-to-a-certain-area).

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution!! 
For tokenAcquisition.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; I am getting an error that says: itokenacquisition does not contain a definition for HttpContextAccessor..

Comment: Rajesh do you have any thoughts on this error I am getting?

Comment: The error you're encountering suggests that the ITokenAcquisition interface does not have a property named HttpContextAccessor. The HttpContextAccessor is part of the ASP.NET Core framework and is typically used to access the current HttpContext within a web application.

Comment: If you want to access the HttpContext in your custom code, you can inject the IHttpContextAccessor into your class.

Comment: I just upgraded to .Net 7 to see if It might resolve some issues. It now recognizes Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI but for the line:
@await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.CdnScripts.IncludeAsync(User)

I am getting the Error:
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'CdnScripts' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 

Any thoughts?

Comment: The error message you are seeing indicates that the CdnScripts namespace is not found in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services namespace. One possible solution is to add a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` package in your project. You can do this by adding the following line to your project file.

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.0" />